# javascript use requestAnimationFrame to define both size and color

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, jquery-animate, requestanimationframe

I wanted my program to create a circle that shrinks until it disappears. The circle should do this in an infinite loop while changing colors(from a starting color to and ending color). The circle works fine but to make the color effects I changed my code, now it only do it a few times while changing colors really fast and then the animation disappears and I don't understand why. The code is unfinished but I needed help to know why can't it change colors while animating the circle. Here's the most recent code:

```
<script>
var mainCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var mainContext = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');

var canvasWidth = mainCanvas.width;
var canvasHeight = mainCanvas.height;

var angle = 0;
var color='#006699';
//var colorend='#000000';
var steps=100;

var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

 function main(){
    var interval = setInterval(function () {

        drawCircle();
            changeColor();
    }, 10);//if i change to a larger value the animation dosen't show
}

function changeColor(){
    var hexc = color.substring(1);
    var decimalc = parseInt(hexc, 16);
    decimalc=decimalc-steps;
    hexc = decimalc.toString(16);
    color= '#'.concat(hexc);
    mainContext.fillStyle = color;
    mainContext.fill();
}


function drawCircle() {
    mainContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    // color in the background
    mainContext.fillStyle = "#EEEEEE";
    mainContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    // draw the circle
    mainContext.beginPath();

    var radius = 10 * Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));
    mainContext.arc(225, 225, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    mainContext.closePath();

    // color in the circle
    mainContext.fillStyle = color;
    mainContext.fill();

    angle += Math.PI / 40;

    if(radius<=0.1){
        return;//exit animation
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(drawCircle);
}



    main();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evalute color by separate bytes, not by sum

```
colorRange={
    create: function(a,b){
        var o = Object.create(this);
        o.a = a.split('').slice(1);
        o.b = b.split('').slice(1);
        var i;
        for(i=0 ; i<3 ; ++i){
            o.a[i] = parseInt( o.a[i], 16 );
            o.b[i] = parseInt(o.b[i], 16) - o.a[i];
        }
        return o;
    },
    get: function(f){ // f is 0..1 color factor
       var n=0;
       return "#"+('00'+(
          +((this.a[n] + this.b[n++]*f) >> 0)
          +( ( this.a[n] + this.b[n]*f) << (n++*4) )
          +( ( this.a[n] + this.b[n]*f) << (n*4) )
              ).toString(16)).slice(-3);
    },
};

var mainCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var mainContext = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');

var canvasWidth = mainCanvas.width;
var canvasHeight = mainCanvas.height;

var angle = 0;
var steps=100;

var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

 function main(){
    q = colorRange.create('#f00', '#00f');
    var x=0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {

        x += 1/16;
        //drawCircle();
        mainContext.fillStyle = q.get(Math.min(x,1));
        mainContext.arc(50,50, 20, 0,Math.PI*2, 0);
        mainContext.fill();
        changeColor();
    }, 200);//if i change to a larger value the animation dosen't show
}

function changeColor(){
    var hexc = color.substring(1);
    var decimalc = parseInt(hexc, 16);
    decimalc=decimalc-steps;
    hexc = decimalc.toString(16);
    color= '#'.concat(hexc);
    mainContext.fillStyle = color;
    mainContext.fill();
}

main();
```

Work sample of your code http://jsfiddle.net/b4zuY/1/

Sorry for my english